# How do I deal with many levels of indentation?

Tags: haskell, indentation, code-organization

I am writing a script that has a very logically complicated loop:

```
main = do
    inFH <- openFile "..." ReadMode
    outFH <- openFile "..." WriteMode

    forM myList $ \ item ->
        ...
        if ... 
            then ...
            else do
                ...
                case ... of
                    Nothing -> ...
                    Just x  -> do
                        ...
                            ...
```

The code soon flies to the right, so I was thinking breaking it into pieces, using for example `where` clauses. The problem is, many of these `...` contain reading/writing statements to the two handles `inFH` and `outFH`, and using a `where` statement will render those two names out of context. I would have to send in these two variables everytime I use a `where` statement.

Is there a better way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In many cases, these deeply-nested indentations are the result of deeply-nested error checking. If that's so for you, you should look into `MaybeT` and its big brother `ExceptT`. These offer a clean way to separate the "what do we do when something went wrong" code from the "what do we do assuming everything goes right" code. In your example, I might write:

```
data CustomError = IfCheckFailed | MaybeCheckFailed

main = handleErrors <=< runExceptT $ do
    inFH  <- liftIO $ openFile ...
    outFH <- liftIO $ openFile ...
    forM myList $ \item -> do
        when (...) (throwError IfCheckFailed)
        ...
        x <- liftMaybe MaybeCheckFailed ...
        ...

liftMaybe :: MonadError e m => e -> Maybe a -> m a
liftMaybe err = maybe (throwError err) return

handleErrors :: Either CustomError a -> IO a
handleErrors (Left err) = case err of
    IfCheckFailed    -> ...
    MaybeCheckFailed -> ...
handleErrors (Right success) = return success
```

Notice that we still increase indentation at the `forM` loop; but the other checks are done "in-line" in `main`, and are handled all at the same indentation level in `handleErrors`.

Answer (score 6):

While there likely are nicer ways to solve your concrete problem (see e.g. [Daniel Wagner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33006197/2751851)), you can always use `let` to introduce a new name within an arbitrary scope. Here is an admittedly nonsensical demo:

```
main = do
    inFH <- return "inf"
    outFH <- return "ouf"

    let subAction = do
            if length inFH > 2
                then print "foo"
                else subSubAction

        subSubAction = case outFH of
            [] -> print "bar"
            _ -> print "baz"

    forM [1..10] $ \ item -> do
        print item
        subAction
```

Comment: Thanks. This is something I over-looked. However, one thing I don't like about using `let` here is because it reverses the reading order -- I'm defining part of the step first and then the comes the rest of the flow. I also don't like having to give part of a logic flow a name, which is another reason I wanted to avoid using `where`.

Answer (score 2):

You should do the same thing you would have done with any other programming language.  Functions should be easy to understand.  This typically means that if it is long there isn't a lot of control flow, otherwise split it up in to separate functions.

So main might look like:

```
main = do
    inFH <- openFile ...
    outFH <- openFile ....

    mapM prcoessItem myList
```

Comment: Um, that's pretty much incompatible with the stated requirement not to pass `inFH` and `outFH` everywhere.