# Composing ExitCodes in Turtle. Why is there no Monad/Monad Transformer instance?

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

I am writing a shell script in Haskell using [`turtle`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.2.2) and would like to know best practices on composing commands that could fail.

Now I have a case expression staircase, like so:

```
runRemote :: MonadIO io => Text -> Text -> io ()
runRemote oldVersion' newVersion' = sh $ do
  mkdir "out"
  e1 <- shell ("command " <> oldVersion') empty
  case e1 of
    ExitFailure n -> cleanup 
    ExitSuccess -> do
      e2 <- shell ("command " <> newVersion') empty
      case e2 of
        ExitFailure n -> cleanup 
        ExitSuccess -> do
          curDir <- pwd
          cd (curDir <.> oldVersion')
          e3 <- shell ("command something else") empty
          case e3 of
           -- ...
           -- And so on...
```

If the `case` expression was expanding on a `Maybe` type, the solution would be to derive a `Monad` instance.

Is there a special reason the library author didn't already derive a `Monad` instance for `ExitCode` or is there a better way to do error handling for Haskell shell code?

Comment: It is impossible to make a `Monad` instance for `ExitCode` because `ExitCode` has kind `*` and the `Monad` type class requires a type with kind `* -> *` (a type that has a type argument).

Comment: You might like [How do I deal with many levels of indentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33005903/791604).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One alternative is using [`(.&&.)` and `(.||.)` from `Turtle.Prelude`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.2.2/docs/Turtle-Prelude.html#v:.-38--38-.).

> `(.&&.) :: Monad m => m ExitCode -> m ExitCode -> m ExitCode`
>
> Analogous to `&&` in Bash
>
> Runs the second command only if the first one returns `ExitSuccess`

> `(.||.) :: Monad m => m ExitCode -> m ExitCode -> m ExitCode`
>
> Analogous to `||` in Bash
>
> Run the second command only if the first one returns `ExitFailure`

They allow you to chain your commands like this (note that everything involved must return an `ExitCode`, including the cleanup):

```
(command1 .&&. command2) .||. cleanup
```

Or, if you need different cleanup actions in each case:

```
(command1 .||. cleanup1) .&&. (command2 .||. cleanup2)
```

By the way, it is worth noting that `ExitCode` is not defined by *turtle* [but rather by *base*, in the `System.Exit` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/System-Exit.html).

Answer (score 2):

`ExitCode` is not a monad, and is not a monad transformer. A monad needs to take a type argument, and a monad transformer needs to take two. `ExitCode` takes none. Now suppose we ignore that not-so-little problem for a bit. Can you come up with a meaningful interpretation of

```
join :: ExitCode (ExitCode a) -> ExitCode a
```

Yeah, I can't either. You could argue reasonably that `shell` should instead produce `Either FailureCode ()`, or perhaps work in `ExceptT FailureCode IO`, but the library authors may have thought that too confusing or inflexible for the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MaybeT` to avoid staircasing this way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Turtle
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

check io = do ec <- lift io
              MaybeT $ case ec of
                         ExitSuccess -> return (Just True)
                         _           -> return Nothing

checkShell a b = check (shell a b)

main = do
  dostuff
  putStrLn "cleaning up"

dostuff = runMaybeT $ do
  checkShell "date" empty
  checkShell "/usr/bin/false" empty
  checkShell "pwd" empty
```