# Conditional computation Maybe (IO ())

Tags: haskell

I am fairly new to Haskell and I would like to express the concept of and IO action that might or might not happen.

Network.URI provides a function to parse a URI

```
parseURI :: String -> Maybe URI
```

in my main function I get the input form the user

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  url <- getLine
  getResource url
```

and the use the parseURI function

```
getResource :: String -> Maybe (IO ())
getResource url = parseURI url >>= doStuff

doStuff :: URI -> Maybe (IO ())
doStuff = undefined
```

As you can see I want to use `>>=` to avoid the `case of` cascade I would get dealing with the Maybes.

I have managed to do so by embedding IO into Maybe. I want to express the case of an IO action that may or may not happen. What should I use? I'm surely not the first one with this problem. I have looked into MaybeT and MonadIO but I am not sure that's what I need.

Specifically, if I move doStuff to `MaybeT IO ()` I'm still stuck with `parseURI url :: Maybe String`. If I lift that to MaybeT now I have `MaybeT Maybe String` and that won't match my `doStuff :: MaybeT IO ()`

I'd like this to look better (if possible) and to understand what is the right direction and what are the mainstream tools to use.

Thank you for your time and advice.

Comment: Can `doStuff` potentially return `Nothing`? If not then you can get away with an `fmap` instead.

Comment: Potentially it can, for example in do stuff I use `uriAuthority :: Maybe URIAuth` to get the domain of the URL

Comment: See also [How do I deal with many levels of indentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33005903/791604).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off: the type of an `IO ()` action that may or may not happen can be simply `IO ()`: you don't care about a result, or whether it was succesful, you just want it executed *if possible*.

If you do care about the success, then there are two options.

- `Maybe (IO ())` is the type of an action or not an action, but whether is a transparent “pure value”. I.e., if you have a `Maybe (IO ())` value on the top-level, then you're able to determine if an action can happen *without actually having to do any `IO` first*. But this can not be the type of a value where you first have to do some IO to determine whether the critical action is going to happen, because in order to bind any IO you already have to be in the `Just` branch of the `Maybe`! So, if success depends on a user-supplied string then this can't be the right type for you.
- `IO (Maybe ())` is the type of an `IO` action which may do anything it needs to determine what action to take. The type is actually equivalent to a `IO Bool` – an `IO` action returning some indicator flag. You may *specify* that `Just ()` means some critical action has happened and `Nothing` means it hasn't, but there's no way to actually see this from the signature.

`MaybeT IO ()` is equivalent to the latter to, and is in fact probably the best type for you application. Only, you need to do the transformer-lifting correctly! `lift` takes an action from *down* in the transformer stack, up to the top of that stack. Hence `lift`! You need it for instance to lift a normal `IO` action like `getLine :: IO String` into the `MaybeT IO` stack:

```
lift getLine :: MaybeT IO String
```

But if you have a pure `Maybe` value, you rather need to “underpin” it to get a `MaybeT IO`. The easiest way to do that is to just use the `MaybeT` constructor directly.

```
getResource :: String -> MaybeT IO ()
getResource url = MaybeT (return $ parseURI url) >>= doStuff

doStuff :: URI -> MaybeT IO ()
doStuff = undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I'm not sure I completely understand so here are are my comments:  wrt `Maybe (IO ())` you say: 

`if you have a Maybe (IO ()) value on the top-level, then you're able to determine if an action can happen without actually having to do any IO first`.

... and that's the case since I'm already doing the IO to get the user input before. I just want to execute it if the input if correct, and that's how I read (probably wrongly) the type: Maybe do something.

The type IO (Maybe ()) reads counter intuitive to me as (to me) it implies already doing something.

Comment: I would rather read `Maybe (IO ())` as _maybe **be able to** do something_. You're right that `IO (Maybe ())` implies that already something can be done before the decision – as you probably need! If you're seperating that IO beforehand which is needed to determine whether an action should be taken, then you don't need any combination of `Maybe` and `IO` at all: just retrieve the necessary value from `IO` and use it to decide with an ordinary conditional (e.g. `when`) whether to execute the other action.

Comment: Also, you mention transformer stack. I'm guessing the stack grown form left to right so by deeper in the stack of a transformer Monad you mean the rightmost type? E.g. in MaybeT IO ()  IO would be the deepest in the stack.

Comment: Yes. In this case rightmost = innermost = lowermost (in the syntax tree).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I have now a better understanding of a lot of things (lift and MabeyT just to mentions a few). You're a good teacher.