# How to use fmap/bind instead of case in this code involving Either and IO?

Tags: haskell

In the code below the case-expression looks similar to the bind implementation for `Either`.

```
doConfirmation :: Registration -> IO (Either Text ())
findRegistration :: Text -> DbData -> Either Text Registration

dbData <- readTVarIO db
case findRegistration rid dbData of
  Right r -> doConfirmation r
  Left err -> return $ Left err
```

How can I write it to take advantage of that and not explicitly `return Left` in case of errors?

Comment: It is times like these that I regret having "dupehammer" powers. Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with many levels of indentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005903/how-do-i-deal-with-many-levels-of-indentation), but I am unusually uncertain about this; if you think that answers your question, let me know, and I will close this one. Or if other folks agree, free to start a close vote; I'll act as if I have three votes instead of five, and cast them towards closing.

Comment: You probably want your main operation to have type `EitherT Text IO ()`.

Comment: @DanielWagner What I find really annoying is that if I were to act on your suggestion and dupehammer the question myself, your useful comment [would be automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195654/242059) =/

Comment: @duplode I can un-delete it if you like :)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson How convenient :) I will accept your offer; thank you.

Comment: @vidi If you feel the suggested question doesn't solve your problem, just ping me and we'll have a second look at it.

Comment: @duplode This is my first Haskell project so I try to use the simplest constructions available in order to keep the complexity under control. I preferred using IO (Either Text ()) because it was simpler to reason about. Now I have to read about ExceptT. I'll try that and be back if I have any questions. Thanks!

Comment: @duplode In the meanwhile I've just read that "It is almost always wrong to wrap an ExceptT, EitherT, or ErrorT around an IO-based transformer stack." ( https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2016/11/exceptions-best-practices-haskell ) So I should to reconsider the approach

Comment: I suggest you still try rewriting your code with `ExceptT IO`, even if you eventually switch back to `IO (Either ...)` or to something else -- if nothing else, it makes for a nice first exercise with monad transformers. By the way, in spite of that strongly-worded quote, the advice in that article is not motivated by some catastrophic flaw with `ExceptT IO`. The issue is more nuanced than that -- it involves trade-offs between different ways of doing sound exception handling. Also note that the author describes the stance taken as "opinionated", in the second paragraph.

Comment: (By the way, with my comment just above I don't mean to say that article is wrong. It makes a very reasonable argument, and it is good to keep in mind the potential issues it mentions. It's just that it won't be the end of the world if you choose not to follow the advice against `Except IO` there for the moment.)

Comment: @duplode I've just updated the question code with the result of my research. I'll have to read about transformers and ExceptT and maybe I will switch to that later. Other comments are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: (1) Your solution effectively makes the question not a duplicate; that being so, I reopened it so that you can post it as an answer. (2) If you plan on recovering from a `RegistrationException`, I suggest having a look at the [readme of the *safe-exceptions* package](https://www.stackage.org/lts-8.2/package/safe-exceptions-0.1.4.0) (expand the first collapsible panel at the linked Stackage page), if you haven't already done so. It is largely consistent with the point of view of the article you found, and offers more immediately applicable practical suggestions than said article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the comments and reading a bit about exception handling in Haskell I did the following:

I changed my potentially failing non-`IO` functions from `Either Text a` to `Either MyException a`.

Then I changed the `IO` functions from `IO (Either e a)` to simply `IO a`, since exceptions are present in `IO` anyway.

Then I also added the `raise` helper function.

This made the code nice and clean. See below:

```
raise :: Exception e => Either e a -> IO a
raise = either throwIO return

doConfirmation :: Registration -> IO ()
findRegistration :: Text -> DbData -> Either RegistrationException Registration

readTVarIO
>>= raise . findRegistration rid
>>= doConfirmation
```

Probably this can be improved further on but for now I'm happy with the result