# 'parse error on input' with case analysis

Tags: haskell

I have the following main function which is supposed to ask two players for their decks, which are chosen from a library of decks in another file, and then run a loop with these inputs.

```
main :: IO()
main = do {
         putStr "Player1 choose deck\n";
         d1 <- getLine; 
         case d1 of 
                {
                 "deck1" -> let {d1 = deck1};
                 _       -> putStr "error"
                };
         putStr "Player2 choose deck\n";
         d2 <- getLine; 
         case d2 of 
                {
               "deck1" -> let {d2 = deck1};
               _       -> putStr "error"
              };
       loop d1 d2
      }
```

The code gets parse errors on the semicolons for the lines:

```
 "deck1" -> let {d1 = deck1};
 "deck1" -> let {d2 = deck1};
```

I've been staring at this for ages and I'm sure it's something simple but would appreciate a fresh pair of eyes to see what's wrong. :)

Comment: Well a `let` statement is typically scoped locally. You can not "reassign" (well in fact you can never assign to begin with) a variable. So this will not work.

Comment: You are trying to use `let x=...` as an assignment in imperative programming, but Haskell is not imperative, and has no assignment. `let` can define _local variables_, which disappear when the scope closes. Your code, if it were Java, roughly reads as `if (...) { int d1 = ...; } else { int d2 = ...; } loop(d1,d2);` and will trigger an undefined variable error.

Comment: The following question is intended to be Socratic and enlightening; I hope you will read and ponder it with that motivation in mind. What type do you believe `d1` should have on the line `putStr "Player2 choose deck\n";`, the type of `"deck1"` or the type of `deck1`? Why?

Comment: Haskell uses indentation to indicate block structure; normally the only time you use curly brackets and semicolons is when you want to stuff everything on the same line for some reason, or in `data` declarations. Try taking out your curly brackets and semicolons.

Comment: @PaulJohnson But the braces and semicolons are correct in this post... the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: A deck should have type [(String,Int,Int)] and deck1 is a specific deck with this type.

Comment: @jack Sure. But I asked about `d1`, not `deck1`.

Comment: Well the type would be a `String` and so looking back through the code it doesn't make sense to say `let {d1 = deck1}` as they're different types, but having changed this to `let {d1' = deck1}` it still doesn't work, which I'm guessing is because of my misunderstanding of how the `let` works.

Comment: @jack And if you write `let {d1' = deck1}` in one branch, but don't define it in the other, what do you expect to happen when the other branch is taken and then you access `d1'` afterwards?

Comment: Yes I see your point, I think this was just a bad way to implement what I wanted. I've changed it that so that in the case where the string is `deck1` then it starts the next case analyses and if that is also `deck1` then it does the loop with those decks. This works for now but would become very complicated if more decks were added to the system.

Comment: @jack Great, I'm glad you got something working! Now that it's working, you can think about how to make it better. You might enjoy my writing on [How do I deal with many levels of indentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33005903/791604); or you may enjoy looking at [`die`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/System-Exit.html#v:die) and pondering its return type for some time.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Haskell's `let` acts differently in a `do` block than it does outside the `do` block. The statement, `let {d2 = deck 1};` is malformed, because the syntax is `let in`. To fix this, you can wrap it in a `do` (eg: `do let {d2 = deck1};`), which should resolve the parse error, but THIS IS NOT WHAT YOU WANT.

There are so many things wrong with the code in the OP that I'm not sure where exactly to start, but here are a few pointers:

- what is deck1/2?
- what is the type of d1/2? Initially, it's a string because you're filling it with `getLine`, but then you're assigning it to `deck1`, which is presumably not a string.
- `let` outside `do` notation must follow `let BINDING in VALUE`. `let BINDING` is not a value and does not make any sense on its own. Moreover, `let BINDING in VALUE` applies the BINDING only in the VALUE. `do`'s `let` is special in that it applies the BINDING to all of the lines following it, but that BINDING is not overwritten. (eg: `do { let x = ""; putStrLn x }` is really just syntactic sugar for `pure "" >>= \x -> putStrLn x` (or maybe `return "" >>= \x -> putStrLn x`, or maybe `(\x -> putStrLn x) ""`).

Try avoiding do notation entirely, I think you're getting confused because do notation allows Haskell to look imperative, like Java, but Haskell is NOT Java. You should start with more pure code and then later explore Monads (and IO) after that. Only then can you really understand `do`.

Comment: So the idea is that there are multiple decks available, however I have only created one so just for testing purposes both `d1` and `d2` are both supposed to be `deck1`. `deck1` is stored in a desperate file and has type `[(String,Int,Int)]`. What I wanted to achieve was that before the game starts, that is before the loop, the players are asked which deck they would like to use and then the game starts with those chosen decks.