# Handling nested if-else-then in do blocks in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've found that I don't know how to handle nested `if-else-then` in `do`-blocks in Haskell.

I know already that I can use a `case`, but that would require all my conditions (`a`, `b` and `c`) to return the same type (`Bool`, so there are only two cases, but I need three distinct ones) and is therefore not as general (correct me if I'm wrong). I have also tried considering using guards here, but I don't know how to make this work in a `do` statement, especially if the `-- something` expressions are meant to be of type `IO ()`.

Suppose I have the following code that is inside a `do`:

```hs
if a then
     -- something
else 
    if b then
        -- something
    else
        if c then
            -- something
        else
            -- something
```

How do I create the equivalent logic but without all the indenting?

Comment: What you have written already requires all of your `-- something` placeholders to return the same type, so your objection to `case` doesn't really apply.

Comment: (1) "that would require all my cases to return the same type and is therefore not as general (correct me if I'm wrong)" -- you also have to return the same type in both branches of an if-expression. Other than syntax, there is essentially no difference between an if-expression and a case-expression on `Bool`. (2) "I have also tried considering using guards here, but I don't know how to make this work in a do statement" -- You can't use guards within a do-block; if-expressions are indeed the right thing to reach for.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke in my original question, it is not the `-- something` placeholders returning the same type that I am trying to avoid, it is the conditions (`a`, `b` and `c`). I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To begin with, it is worth noting that if-expressions do not actually require extra indentation (if-within-do used to be an exception, but Haskell 2010 eliminated that). That means you might collapse all the extra indentation:

```
test = do
    len <- length <$> getLine
    if len < 4
    then putStrLn "Short"
    else if len > 6
    then putStrLn "Long"
    else putStrLn "Mid"
```

Personally, though, I don't find that too pleasing aesthetically, as I feel *some* indentation makes if-expressions easier to follow. A nice alternative is using [the `MultiWayIf` extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.4/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#multi-way-if-expressions):

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}

test = do
    len <- length <$> getLine
    if | len < 4 -> putStrLn "Short"
       | len > 6 -> putStrLn "Long"
       | otherwise -> putStrLn "Mid"
```

On a final note, nested if-expressions getting unwieldy might reveal a good occasion for breaking things down in separate definitions, or otherwise reorganising your code. See also: [*How do I deal with many levels of indentation?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33005903/2751851)

Comment: Thank you! This is _exactly_ what I was looking for as an answer. Sorry for my typo in my original question. Haskell is great fun so far!

Comment: @Utagai You're welcome, and worry not -- if you only knew how many typos I make in my posts... :)

Comment: @Utagai, if you don't want to use `MultiWayIf`, you can use `case () of _ | ...`. Uglier, but standard.

Comment: Thanks @dfeuer, didn't realize I could use a `case` like that but reading it, I see why it works. Thank you!