# Map Functor inside another Functor in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functor, yesod

I should get `Maybe UserId` from [maybeAuth](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.5/yesod-auth-1.6.8/Yesod-Auth.html#v:maybeAuth)

I am going to do it this way:

```
... = do
  muserId <- (entityKey <$>) <$> maybeAuth
...
```

So, I am looking to map `Functor` inside another `Functor`. I heard about Functor composition, is it my case?

Can I improve it using Functor Composition or something else?

Comment: Given that you claim to be in a `do` block, you probably can't improve it much. [Functors compose, but monads don't.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7040844/791604) But see also [`MaybeT`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33005903/791604), depending on what you want to happen with `Nothing`s.

Comment: @DanielWagner There's a (slim) chance he's in `ApplicativeDo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general approach, you could use [Data.Functor.Compose](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html). Here's an example that composes a list of maybes:

```
Prelude Data.Functor.Compose> ff = Compose [Just 42, Just 1337, Nothing, Just 2112]
Prelude Data.Functor.Compose> :t ff
ff :: Num a => Compose [] Maybe a
Prelude Data.Functor.Compose> fmap (show . (+1)) ff
Compose [Just "43",Just "1338",Nothing,Just "2113"]
```

Comment: Of course, `getCompose (fmap f (Compose x))` isn't a huge improvement over `fmap (fmap f) x`.

Comment: (Unless you want to factor out a helper like `let deepMap f = getCompose . fmap f . Compose in deepMap entityKey maybeAuth`.)

Comment: I found this library that looks interesting: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition-extra-2.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Syntax.html#v:-60--36--36--62-

Comment: Do you think `fmap f <$> x` looks better?