# Binding a Maybe within another monad to avoid case stairway of doom?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm fetching a user from a database with a key I'm fetching from an api (`uid`). The `uid` is a `Maybe ByteString`, and so I can either `case` check whether it's a `Maybe` and *then* run the `Redis` monad, or somehow bind it to `DB.hget`. Below is an incorrect implementation where the `uid` is bound to the `hget` function, but it obviously doesn't work since it's returning a `Maybe` when it should be a `Redis` monad. What's an elegant solution to this that avoids verbose case statements?

```
getUser :: B.ByteString  -> ReaderT LobbyEnv IO User
getUser token =  do
  env <- ask
  uid <- liftIO $ verifyToken token <&> fmap encodeUtf8
  liftIO $ DB.runRedis (env^.db) $ do
    r <- uid >>= DB.hget "users" <&> either (return Nothing) (fmap (BN.decode . BL.fromStrict)) 
    case r of
      Nothing -> throwIO UNKNOWN_ERROR
      Just g -> pure g
```

Comment: Please add some more information, it's hard to get behind what the local types are. And always link to relevant libraries in whose context you're asking the question. I.e. here [hedis](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis).

Comment: Maybe just `Data.Maybe.maybe (throwIO UNKNOWN_ERROR) pure r`?

Comment: It may be excessive for this purpose, but I suppose `MaybeT m a` would be the usual way of constructing `m (Maybe a)` actions without `case` nesting; or, instead of converting that `Either` result to `Maybe`, you could keep the `Either` and use `ExceptT e m a` to deal with the `m (Either e a)` actions similarly. In that case, you have the option of using `Left` instead of `throwIO`, and moving the `throwIO` outside the block if you still want to convert it to an unchecked exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I deal with many levels of indentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33005903/791604)