# Simplification of way too long Haskell function

Tags: haskell

I wrote a function to query currency exchanges rate from an API. It works fine, but the code is way too long and unreadable. I thought someone would be able to help me simplify this, especially because there are many repeated patterns and operators like the repeated use of

EDIT: I didn't realize that binding anything to `pure` is absolutely useless!

```hs
... <&> (=<<) (something >>= pure) ...
```

I've just started learning Haskell and therefore don't know many clever operators/functions/lenses that could be used here.

Btw, I am aware that do-notation exists.

```hs
forex :: (String, String) -> IO (Maybe (Scientific, UnixTime))
forex cp = (get ("https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=" ++ uncurry (++) cp) <&> decode . flip (^.) responseBody <&> (=<<) (parseMaybe (.: "rates") >>= pure) :: IO (Maybe (Map Key (Map Key Scientific)))) <&> (=<<) (Data.Map.lookup (fromString (uncurry (++) cp)) >>= pure) <&> (=<<) ((pure . toList) >>= pure) <&> (=<<) (pure . map snd >>= pure) <&> fmap (\y -> (head y, UnixTime ((CTime . fromRight 0 . floatingOrInteger) (y !! 1)) 0))
```

The received JSON looks like this

```json
{"rates":{"EURUSD":{"rate":1.087583,"timestamp":1649600523}},"code":200}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whenever you see a repeated pattern like that, you often can (and should) bring it out into its own function which can then be reused. For example, `pat f = (=<<) (f >>= pure)`. Then, instead of writing that each time, you can just use `pat`.

Comment: You break your parsing into two phases, one in aeson's parser monad and one in `Maybe`. Consider merging them so that it all happens in aeson's monad; e.g. `do { rates <- o .: "rates"; current <- rates .: fromString (c ++ p); rate <- current .: "rate"; timestamp <- current .: "timestamp"; pure (rate, UnixTime (CTime timestamp) 0) } :: Parser (Scientific, UnixTime)` lets you elide rather a lot of your fumbling around with `Maybe`s, `fmap`s, and `Either`s; it also handles malformed or surprisingly-formed JSON data more predictably than your `toList`, `head`, and `(!!)` stuff.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wow, that *is* too long. Let's take it step by step; by the end, we will arrive at the following code snippet which I find much more natural to read but which performs exactly the same computation:

```
forex (c, p) = extractFirstTime c p
    <$> get ("https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=" ++ c ++ p)

extractFirstTime c p response = firstTime
    <$> parseAndLookUp c p (response ^. responseBody)

parseAndLookUp c p body =
    decode body >>=
    parseMaybe (.: "rates") >>=
    Data.Map.lookup (fromString (c ++ p))

firstTime = case Data.Map.elems m of
    k:t:_ -> (k, UnixTime ((CTime . fromRight 0 . floatingOrInteger) t) 0)
```

Let's see how.

1. To start, I think it's easier to see and edit if there are strategically chosen line breaks.

   ```
   forex cp =
       (get ("https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=" ++ uncurry (++) cp)
           <&> decode . flip (^.) responseBody
           <&> (=<<) (parseMaybe (.: "rates") >>= pure)
           :: IO (Maybe (Map Key (Map Key Scientific)))
       )
       <&> (=<<) (Data.Map.lookup (fromString (uncurry (++) cp)) >>= pure)
       <&> (=<<) ((pure . toList) >>= pure)
       <&> (=<<) (pure . map snd >>= pure)
       <&> fmap (\y -> (head y, UnixTime ((CTime . fromRight 0 . floatingOrInteger) (y !! 1)) 0))
   ```
2. One of the monad laws is `m >>= pure = m`, so let's delete `>>= pure` everywhere. (One each on lines 4, 7, 8, and 9.)

   ```
   forex cp =
       (get ("https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=" ++ uncurry (++) cp)
           <&> decode . flip (^.) responseBody
           <&> (=<<) (parseMaybe (.: "rates"))
           :: IO (Maybe (Map Key (Map Key Scientific)))
       )
       <&> (=<<) Data.Map.lookup (fromString (uncurry (++) cp))
       <&> (=<<) (pure . toList)
       <&> (=<<) (pure . map snd)
       <&> fmap (\y -> (head y, UnixTime ((CTime . fromRight 0 . floatingOrInteger) (y !! 1)) 0))
   ```
3. Another monad law is `m >>= pure . f = fmap f m`. Let's simplify with that law where possible. (One each on lines 8 and 9.)

   ```
   forex cp =
       (get ("https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=" ++ uncurry (++) cp)
           <&> decode . flip (^.) responseBody
           <&> (=<<) (parseMaybe (.: "rates"))
           :: IO (Maybe (Map Key (Map Key Scientific)))
       )
       <&> (=<<) Data.Map.lookup (fromString (uncurry (++) cp))
       <&> fmap toList
       <&> fmap (map snd)
       <&> fmap (\y -> (head y, UnixTime ((CTime . fromRight 0 . floatingOrInteger) (y !! 1)) 0))
   ```
4. The uses of `uncurry` are happening because we're not pattern-matching on `cp`. Let's fix that up. (Lines 1, 2, and 7.)

   ```
   forex (c, p) =
       (get ("https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=" ++ c ++ p)
           <&> decode . flip (^.) responseBody
           <&> (=<<) (parseMaybe (.: "rates"))
           :: IO (Maybe (Map Key (Map Key Scientific)))
       )
       <&> (=<<) Data.Map.lookup (fromString (c ++ p))
       <&> fmap toList
       <&> fmap (map snd)
       <&> fmap (\y -> (head y, UnixTime ((CTime . fromRight 0 . floatingOrInteger) (y !! 1)) 0))
   ```
5. My mental type-checker is going nuts. Let's split this calculation into three different kinds of things: one that works in `IO`, one that works in `Maybe`, and one that is pure. First let's split the `IO` from everything else.

   ```
   forex (c, p) = extractFirstTime c p
       <$> get ("https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=" ++ c ++ p)

   extractFirstTime c p response = response
       & decode . flip (^.) responseBody
       & (=<<) (parseMaybe (.: "rates"))
       & (=<<) Data.Map.lookup (fromString (c ++ p))
       & fmap toList
       & fmap (map snd)
       & fmap (\y -> (head y, UnixTime ((CTime . fromRight 0 . floatingOrInteger) (y !! 1)) 0))
   ```
6. Now let's split out the `Maybe` parts.

   ```
   forex (c, p) = extractFirstTime c p
       <$> get ("https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=" ++ c ++ p)

   extractFirstTime c p response = parseAndLookUp c p (response ^. responseBody)
       & fmap toList
       & fmap (map snd)
       & fmap (\y -> (head y, UnixTime ((CTime . fromRight 0 . floatingOrInteger) (y !! 1)) 0))

   parseAndLookUp c p body =
       decode body >>=
       parseMaybe (.: "rates") >>=
       Data.Map.lookup (fromString (c ++ p))
   ```
7. And let's split out the pure parts. One of the functor laws is `fmap f . fmap g = fmap (f . g)`, so we can merge the three `fmap`s in `extractFirstTime`. At that point, the two arguments to `(&)` that remain are short enough that we can inline the definition of `(&)`. I'll also use the name `(<$>)` instead of `fmap`; I think it reads a bit clearer.

   ```
   forex (c, p) = extractFirstTime c p
       <$> get ("https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=" ++ c ++ p)

   extractFirstTime c p response = firstTime
       <$> parseAndLookUp c p (response ^. responseBody)

   parseAndLookUp c p body =
       decode body >>=
       parseMaybe (.: "rates") >>=
       Data.Map.lookup (fromString (c ++ p))

   firstTime m = m
       & toList
       & map snd
       & (\y -> (head y, UnixTime ((CTime . fromRight 0 . floatingOrInteger) (y !! 1)) 0))
   ```
8. `Data.Map` has a name for `map snd . toList`, namely, `elems`. Instead of using `head` and `!!`, let's use pattern matching to pick out the elements we want. (All changes are in `firstTime`.)

   ```
   forex (c, p) = extractFirstTime c p
       <$> get ("https://www.freeforexapi.com/api/live?pairs=" ++ c ++ p)

   extractFirstTime c p response = firstTime
       <$> parseAndLookUp c p (response ^. responseBody)

   parseAndLookUp c p body =
       decode body >>=
       parseMaybe (.: "rates") >>=
       Data.Map.lookup (fromString (c ++ p))

   firstTime = case Data.Map.elems m of
       k:t:_ -> (k, UnixTime ((CTime . fromRight 0 . floatingOrInteger) t) 0)
   ```

There are likely additional beautifying things that could be done (adding type signatures comes to mind, and I have several ideas that change/improve the behavior of the code), but I think by this point you have something that's fairly reasonable to read and understand. Along the way, making things readable has, as a side effect, eliminated the repeated code snippets you found unnerving, so that's a little bonus; but if they had remained, it would be very natural to try to address them as an additional step.

Comment: Wow, thank you for that very good answer!
Now the only thing that kind of annoys me is the handling of types with nested monads,
IO (Maybe ...) in this case, isn't there any operator that eliminates the need for a double bind when using such types?

Comment: Also, should I switch from IO (Maybe ...) to Maybe (IO ... )?

Comment: @Fabus1184 Take a look at [this question on avoiding indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33005903/791604) for a quick tutorial on using monad transformers to avoid double binds. (But I don't think it's particularly idiomatic here.) You should not switch from `IO (Maybe ...)` to `Maybe (IO ...)` because the latter promises to know whether it is `Just` or `Nothing` without doing any `IO`, which is a promise you can't possibly uphold.