# How to best handle IO Bool logic?

Tags: haskell

I see myself using this pattern a lot:

```
f x = do
  -- predicate :: a -> IO Bool
  b <- predicate x
  if b then 
    rest ()
  else
    return ()
  where
    rest () = do
      -- rest of my IO operations
```

is there a pattern other people use to remove the if then else where clauses? How do you best work with control flow and IO Bool?

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I deal with many levels of indentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005903/how-do-i-deal-with-many-levels-of-indentation).

Comment: why do you write `rest ()` instead of just `rest`, or instead of writing `then do` and the operations?

Comment: because that's the way I got it to work and didn't know about the `then do` idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [`when`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:when) and [`unless`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:unless).

```hs
f x = do
  b <- predicate x
  when b $ do
    -- rest of the IO operation
```

In the [extra](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra) package there also is [`whenM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.12/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html#v:whenM).

Answer (score 2):

In additional to `when`, another thing that's handy – and not specific to booleans – is to use `-XLambdaCase` and an open bind operator to avoid having to introduce a variable:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

f x = do
   predicate >>= \case
     True -> rest ()
     False -> return ()
  where
    rest () = do
      ...
```

Incidentally, if `when` had its arguments flipped then this could be used in that style too:

```
thenfore :: m () -> Bool -> m ()
thenfore = flip when

f x = do
   predicate >>= thenfore (rest ())
  where
    rest () = do
      ...
```

...or, inlining `rest`,

```
f x = do
   predicate >>= thenfore`id`do
      ...
```

Explanation on the use of `id` as an operator: notice that `id :: a -> a` is strictly more general than the function-application operator `($) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b)`, so it can be used in the same way, but it has higher precedence and can thus be combined with `>>=` as done above.